# Sync date with change in start day of week?

Tags: ios, calendar, weekday, jtcalendar

Component shows start day of week as Sunday. In my requirements week day can start from any day of the week, month day should in sync with it.

I am changing week day from Sunday to Monday, but today's date is showing on next day of week which wrong.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to change the start day week. But could not get to relates the data content from month.

Comment: This needs to be closed as "too broad" or "no [mcve]", as there is no detail to help someone wishing to answer.